# Alamofire iOS13

Tags: swift, alamofire

I want to update my code in the past when I used swift 2 or 3. I am stuck where I want to use  Alamofire but the way to use it changed and I don't know how to use it anymore. Can anybody update this part of the code and explain a little bit? Thank you.
This is the original code.

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, url)
            .response{ (request, response, data, error) in
                let xml = SWXMLHash.parse(data!)
                let sunsetTime = xml["result"]["rise_and_set"]["sunset_hm"].element?.text
                self.sunsetTimeLabel.text = sunsetTime
                self.getDateFromString(sunsetTime,year: comp.year,month: comp.month,day: comp.day)
                if (error != nil) {
                    print(error)
                }
        }
```

this is the code I was writing.

```
AF.request(url, method: .post).responseJSON { (responseData)  in
            let xml = SWXMLHash.parse(responseData as Data)
            let sunsetTime = xml["result"]["rise_and_set"]["sunset_hm"].element?.text
            self.sunsetTimeLabel.text = sunsetTime
```

There is an error saying "Cannot convert value of type 'AFDataResponse' (aka 'DataResponse') to type 'Data' in coercion"

Comment: Unrelated, is this request really creating/updating some resource on your server? I.e., should this really be a `POST` request? If so, you’d usually be supplying parameters to be saved on the server. This feels suspiciously like it should be a `GET` request. (The fact that the server accepts a `POST` request is not relevant; it’s a question of what the right semantics are.) It’s something to look at after you get your immediate problem behind you. See [GET vs POST](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp).

Answer (score 1):

Your first code snippet is Alamofire 3 syntax. I infer from the second code snippet that you are now using Alamofire 5.

There are a few issues:

1. You are calling `responseJSON` (which you’d only use if your response was JSON, not XML). Use `response` or, better, `responseData`.
2. The `response` object passed to this closure is not a `Data`, itself. In the case of `responseData` method, it is a `AFDataResponse` object, which has a `data` property (which is a `Data?`). You have to extract the `Data` object from this `AFDataResponse`, either by unwrapping the contents of the `data` property, or from the `result` (see next point).
3. You should probably check for `success` or `failure` and extract the `Data` from the `response.result` object.

So, pulling this together, you end up with something like:

```
AF.request(url, method: .post).responseData { response in
    switch response.result {
    case .failure(let error):
        print(error)

    case .success(let data):
        let xml = SWXMLHash.parse(data)
        ...
    }
}
```